# Error "cannot be resolved to a type" using the Factory Method

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-method

I'm trying to use the design pattern "Factory Method" on DAO. There are some problems with the type resolving when I call the method to create the correct instance.
This is the main where I call the method and I get the error:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int scelta=1;

        Parametri<InterfacciaTO> p=new Parametri<InterfacciaTO>();
        //here I get the error
        DaoInterface dao=(DaoInterface) new MySqlDAO.getInstance(scelta,p);
    }
}
```

These are the classes that I use to implement the FactoryMethod.

```
public interface DaoFactory {

    public abstract Object getInstance(int code,Parametri<InterfacciaTO> param);

}

public  class MySqlDAO implements DaoFactory {

    @Override
    public DaoInterface getInstance(int code, Parametri<InterfacciaTO> param) {
        switch(code){
        case Indici.UTENTEDAO: return new UtenteDAO();
        }
        return null;
    }   
}

public interface DaoInterface {

    public abstract void create(int code,Parametri<InterfacciaTO> param);

    public abstract void delete(int code,Parametri<InterfacciaTO> param);

    public abstract void update(int code,Parametri<InterfacciaTO> param);

    public abstract void search(int code,Parametri<InterfacciaTO> param);

}

public class UtenteDAO implements DaoInterface {

    @Override
    public void create(int code, Parametri<InterfacciaTO> param) {
        System.out.println("CIAU");

    }

    @Override
    public void delete(int code, Parametri<InterfacciaTO> param) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void update(int code, Parametri<InterfacciaTO> param) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void search(int code, Parametri<InterfacciaTO> param) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`new MySqlDAO.getInstance(scelta,p);` doesn't make any sense and won't compile.

The `new` keyword is associated with creating an instance of an object through its constructor, which requires an explicit invocation to the constructor (e.g. `new MySqlDAO()` - note the parenthesis).

However, you probably want to invoke `MySqlDAO.getInstance(scelta,p)` as a `static` method (fix it in `MySqlDAO` too) if it's supposed to be a singleton.

You probably also want to actually **make** it a singleton.